# AngularJS : directive that repeats wrapped element over list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create an angular-js directive that encapsules editing a list of items: It should iterate over a list, repeating the wrapped element of the directive for every item and add some controls to each line (deleting elements, moving elements around, ...). Ideally I would like to use the directive like this:

```
<edit-list list="mylist">
    <input ng-model="item.name">
    <input ng-model="item.location">
</edit-list>
```

where the directives template should be like this (as demonstration I added a button for deleting items):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list track by $index">
    <span ng-transclude></span><button ng-click="delete_item($index)">
</div>
```

However, I can't get this to work. I tried to adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18222546/3628994) which manages to repeat the wrapped element over a list, however the plunker does  not work anymore with modern angularjs versions (see my forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v4v6Q2?p=preview) which changes only the version of angularjs).

Nevertheless, [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/pIAe0c?p=preview) is a plunker tries to implement what I want to accomplish, but failes: It seems like the transcluded element can't see the item anymore. This makes sense given the documentation for ng-transclude, but I could not figure out how to make the wrapped element see the scope of the directive again.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/GZsfp0HaeAVg5NjMBtGC?p=preview and made some changes:

1. Your goal is to `ng-repeat` over a list. There is no need for `ng-transclude` since you already binding your list to your directive.
2. I removed the reference to `ng-transclude` in your directive
3. I amended your `delete` method to pluck the proper item from the list.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem is that I would like to use the directive on a variety of different lists, all requiring different HTML to display and edit the single items. With other words: I want to encapsule the loop with the list-editing functionality (removing items etc.) into a component while still being able to change how the single list items are displayed. When putting the display of the items into the directives template like you did, I cannot change this anymore for different lists. What would be the right way to accomplish this?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're after.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear. I updated my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pIAe0c?p=preview) to showcase what I am after: Now I have two different lists. The items in the two lists are structured differently, thus I need different ways to display them. Because of this, I would like to hand the template for displaying single items somehow to the directive. Wrapping it into the directive seemed easiest to me, but maybe there is a better way. I hope now my problem is easier to understand.

Comment: I think I more or less accomplished what I want to have. However I am not sure whether is is good angularjs practice. Especially, I would prefer my directive to have it's own scope. But then I do not know how to access the outside list which is at the moment given in a repeat expression. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ImNxY38NpnakcqgFkGvr?p=preview) for my new version.